# Store parameter pack as tuple references

Tags: c++11, tuples, variadic-templates, variadic-functions, perfect-forwarding

I am trying to store the parameter pack of lvalue references of a variadic template for later use.

I have the following working for now.

```
template <typename... Ts>
class Foo {
private:
        std::tuple<Ts...> m_args;
public:
       template<typename... Args>
       Foo(Args&&... args) : m_args(std::make_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
       {
       }
 };

 int main() {
     int x = 10;
     int y = 20;
     Foo<int, int> foo(x, y);
 }
```

However, I would like to store the parameter pack as a reference so that I can access the same object later.
I am not sure how I can do that. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I can imagine, is the use of `std::forward_as_tuple`.

Unfortunately I don't see a way to use it with perfect forwarding: if you want register values in a tuple inside a class, you have to decide the type of the tuple one time for all.

The best I can imagine is a tuple of const references; something as follows

```
template <typename ... Ts>
class Foo
 {
   private:
      std::tuple<Ts const & ...> m_args;

   public:
      Foo (Ts const & ... as) : m_args{std::forward_as_tuple(as...)}
       { }
 };
```

I hope isn't necessary remember you how dangling references can be dangerous for a solution based on a tuple of references.

Comment: The type is known and it is only the number of arguments that is going to vary.

Comment: @ZincFur - Do you mean that all `Ts...` types are the same type? So why do you use `std::tuple` and not `std::array`?

Comment: I dont want dynamic initialization neither do I want to specify the number of args as a template parameter. Is it still possible to use std::array to store the parameter pack?

Comment: @ZincFur - what about the use of SFINAE to impose that the number of `Args...` typenames is exactly the size of the `std::array`? And, yes, you can use a `std::array` to store a parameter pack (if `m_args` is a `std::array<T, Dim>`, you can write `Foo (Args const & ... as) : m_args{{ as... }}`) but, unfortunately, you can't make arrays of references.